# what are the backtick symbols in vs user mode debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have the following c++ code compiled into `Program.exe` using vs12

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << "in ctor\n";
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        std::cout << "in dtor\n";
    }

    std::string s;
};

int main()
{
    foo f{};
}
```

Then I go to "[Tools->Launch Under Debugger...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406273(v=vs.85).aspx)" and type the following command in the debugger immediate window

```
x program!*foo*
```

This gives me the following output

```
0:000> x program!*foo*
00007ff6`11ce4b00 Program!foo::~foo (void)
00007ff6`11ceaef0 Program!`foo::~foo'::`1'::dtor$0 (void)
00007ff6`11ce48f0 Program!foo::foo (void)
00007ff6`11ceae90 Program!`foo::foo'::`1'::dtor$0 (void)
```

I understand the first output is `foo`'s destructor and the third one is `foo`'s constructor. What are the second and fourth ones (the ones with the backticks) ?. More generally, what are the other places where I might see backticks in the user mode debugger?

Interestingly, the backtick functions go away if any of the following are done

- Remove `std::cout` statements
- Remove `std::string s`
- Add the `throw()` keyword in front of the constructor and destructor

This seems to suggest the backtick functions have something to do with exception handling

Answer (score 3):

These are internal names generated by the Microsoft compiler for "glue" functions that help things fit together, but don't correspond directly to a line of source code. It is normal.

There are other situations where you'll see similar internal names with backticks, such as using lambda functions, or calling a function that's declared inside a struct that's inside another function.

Other compilers have different ways of representing similar nameless blocks of code; the standard doesn't dictate any particular behavior here, and it's only observable via the debugger anyway.

Comment: Presumably the backtick was chosen because it's not used in C++, so it can't be confused for any construct from C++ source code.

Comment: Definitely. Of course there are many symbols to choose from that fit that profile. In fact, `dtor$0` is using the `$` just because it's outside the range of legal characters.

Comment: Except that a number of C and C++ compilers do permit `$` in identifiers as an extension.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think Dev Studio allowed this, but apparently they do! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d.aspx

Comment: The only ASCII printable characters that aren't used in C and C++ (and aren't part of the *basic source character set*) are `'$'`, `'@'`, and ``'`'``.